# Ошибка подключения Git к Laravel

Tags: laravel

Warning: require(D:\OSPanel\domains\geekshop\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):

failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

D:\OSPanel\domains\geekshop\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git не узнаёт команду: нужно в системных переменных Виндовс указать путь к GIT.

"C:\path\to\git\bin";"C:\path\to\git\cmd"